# No transition matching 3 found for current state

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking at the ros2 lifecycles demo here: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/foxy/lifecycle/src/lifecycle_talker.cpp

According to the [Lifecycles page](https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html) of ROS2 if an exception occurs in any of the primary states then the `on_error` method should be called, which in turn, on `SUCCESS` reverts to the `Unconfigured` state, and on `FAILURE`it goes to `Finalized` and eventually the node gets shutdown.

For the sake of the example I'll throw an exception from within one of the transition callbacks, e.g., `on_activate`.

```
on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &)
{
  throw std::runtime_error("some_error");
  ...
```

With this change in place I see the following transitions happening (see roslaunch  output of command `ros2 launch  lifecycle lifecycle_demo.launch.py` )

```
[lifecycle_listener-2] [INFO] [1627469418.643524277] [lc_listener]: notify callback: Transition from state activating to errorprocessing
[lifecycle_listener-2] [INFO] [1627469418.643625385] [lc_listener]: notify callback: Transition from state errorprocessing to unconfigured
[lifecycle_service_client-3] [WARN] [1627469418.643600791] [lc_client]: Failed to trigger transition 3
```

I understand why it transitions to errorprocessing and then to unconfigured. However it then tries to transition to "3" which is the `TRANSITION_ACTIVATE` transition and it fails to do so since that is not a valid transition (`Unconfigured` -> `Active`)

I don't understand though, why is it trying transition to activate since I or any other node didn't explicitly trigger this transition? What can I do to solve this?

Here's also the full list of transitions the node goes through, in case it's helpful

```
ros2 topic echo /lc_talker/transition_event
timestamp: 0
transition:
  id: 0
  label: ''
start_state:
  id: 1
  label: unconfigured
goal_state:
  id: 10
  label: configuring
---
timestamp: 0
transition:
  id: 0
  label: ''
start_state:
  id: 10
  label: configuring
goal_state:
  id: 2
  label: inactive
---
timestamp: 0
transition:
  id: 0
  label: ''
start_state:
  id: 2
  label: inactive
goal_state:
  id: 13
  label: activating
---
timestamp: 0
transition:
  id: 0
  label: ''
start_state:
  id: 13
  label: activating
goal_state:
  id: 15
  label: errorprocessing
---
timestamp: 0
transition:
  id: 0
  label: ''
start_state:
  id: 15
  label: errorprocessing
goal_state:
  id: 1
  label: unconfigured
---
```

### System Information

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Latest version of the PPA packages of ROS Foxy.

Any pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383441/no-transition-matching-3-found-for-current-state/) by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2021-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-07-28**:
Not 100% sure, but something I noted - looking at the timestamps of the output you posted, the warning

`[WARN] [1627469418.643600791] [lc_client]: Failed to trigger transition 3`

actually happens **before** the transition to unconfigured

`[INFO] [1627469418.643625385] [lc_listener]: notify callback: Transition from state errorprocessing to unconfigured`

by some number of microseconds.

Does the process die after the warning, or can you query the lifecycle node's state manually? Could be that its just a bit of confusion due to the way the scheduler bundled the different logging processes?

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2021-07-29**:
Ah, yoiu're right!
Nice catch!

Do you want to form it into an answer? I'd be happy to approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[moving my comment down into the answers]

Looking at the timestamps of the output you posted, the warning

```
[WARN] [1627469418.6436**00791**] [lc_client]: Failed to trigger transition 3
```

actually happens before the transition to unconfigured

```
[INFO] [1627469418.6436**25385**] [lc_listener]: notify callback: Transition from state errorprocessing to unconfigured
```

by some number of microseconds.

If the process didn't die after the warning, it could be that its just a bit of confusion due to the way the scheduler bundled the different logging processes

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1